# Wireless download slow on Bootcamp (Upload is fine)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, bootcamp, windows

I have the Mid 2015 Macbook Pro Retina 15" (11,4) and originally installed Windows 10 Pro using Bootcamp assistant.

I'm having issues with downloading over wireless (no / limited issues uploading), when I try to download any file more than about 1MB it will start off fine (anywhere from 400KB-1.2MB/s) and then suddenly spike down to something ridiculous (usually 15KB/s) and then stall completely but still say it's going at 15KB/s, this is making it pretty much impossible to download any file.

I have tried resetting my routers configuration, reinstalling windows (I used the media creation tool and brigadier without any issues), reset the SMC and made sure I'm on the most clear WLAN channel and am still experiencing this issue.

I have also tested to make sure this does not happen on other wireless devices and can confirm my phone is downloading near my downlink speed (~25Mb/s) but my laptop is still spiking around that speed and going straight down.

This shows the inital spike up, spike down and halting that I described and also shows that it doesn't happen during upload.

[image: Chart showing wireless speedtest]

For comparison here is a test done immediately after over Ethernet.

[image: Chart showing Ethernet speedtest]

I also had this issue when I had a mid 2010 MacBook Pro running Windows 7.

I'll link to some more relevant information below.

- Mobile speedtest: www.speedtest.net/my-result/a/2619288419
- SysInfo Export: pastebin.com/9c6mHQry
- Link speed: ↓ 25,4 Mbit/s // ↑8,2 Mbit/s
- Wireless channels in use: imgur.com/uSzOuL4
- Driver details: imgur.com/q0I8Fgy (Still happens with .49 provided by apple software update and any other versions downloaded elsewhere)

[Sorry about that mess, sadly I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links]
The wireless NIC is part of the Broadcom BCM43XX series.
If anyone has any idea how to fix this that'd be great, feel free to ask for more information if necessary!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be working with a different router now (I was reluctant to test this as my backup router is ISP provided) but I will revisit this if problems persist.